# R: launch separate threads for function and wait for result

Tags: r, multithreading

I've a function fA in R calling three times the same function fB like :

```
fA <- function(x){
 r1 <- fB(param1)
 r2 <- fB(param2)
 r3 <- fB(param3)
 return(c(r1,r2,r3))
}
```

the parameter of fBs function are computed in fA function. But to go faster how can I launch every fB function in background and wait for the results ( so the thre fB function are executed in parallel )

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not too long ago, the [`parallel` package](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf) was added to the R core. Have a look at functions like `mclapply` and `parLapply` for functions that mimic the behavior of `lapply` but execute in parallel. `mclapply` uses process forking, and `parLapply` uses clusters (e.g. a SOCK cluster). I would study the documentation of the parallel package to see what your specific situation requires.